# Java regular expression, disallow forward-slash

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a regular expression that validates whether a string contains a forward-slash.  If a forward-slash is present the validation fails.  The string has to pass even if it is empty.

This is what I have done so far:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\ ]*$"
```

Comment: What if it contains both slashes?

Comment: The string can be empty.  Thank you.

Comment: If both should fail.

Comment: And what if it contains neither of slashes e.g. "foo"

Comment: @csharpfolk the important is the string does not have forward-slash,

Comment: So really, backslashes aren't part of the validation at all. It's just that the `String` can't contain a forward slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to assert that there cannot be any forward slashes, that looks like `(?!.*\/)`. From there, make sure you find at least one backward slash, or you find nothing (the end of the line):

```
^(?!.*\/)((?:.*\\.*)|$)
```

You can see it matching [here](https://regex101.com/r/cG6rR6/3). Note that there are two matches in the right hand column, one for the empty regex, and one for the line that contains a backward slash.

**Edit:** If the requirement is *only* to make sure that the string does not have any forward slashes, then the regex is easier. You just take the negative lookahead from the above regex.

```
^(?!.*\/).*$
```

You can see that matching [here](https://regex101.com/r/oN9pG9/1).

Comment: Thank you, it works!  I have one more question, how to append this one to another regular expression?

Comment: You can't really "append" regular expressions. Since you're using Java, you could call a method to do the matching twice with different regexes, e.g. call matcher.find() multiple times.

Comment: How can add in your expression, not allowing : ?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the comments correctly, then you don't require a backslash for the expression to pass - you just want to make sure there are no forward slashes.  In that case, you could simply use `^[^/]*$`  You should not need any type of lookahead for this.

To interpret this expression a bit: this expression matches the beginning of the string (`^`) followed by zero or more non-slash characters (`[^/]*`), followed by end of string (`$`).  The square brackets usually indicate that you want to match any character inside of them, but in this case, the leading `^` inverts that portion of the expression, so it will match any character that is NOT a slash.  The `*` indicates that we want to attempt that match zero or more times as needed for the pattern to work.